# How can I compare two audio files frequency in react-native or javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

How can I compare two audio frequencies,

I want to compare an audio file with an audio sample that I have already collected.

Please suggest me how can I do this thing and which library I should use?

Comment: you need to create your own custom native module.